# Problems with wordcount in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

There was a problem using hive to do wordcount.

My hive command is like

```
select word, count(1) as count 
from (select explode(split(word, ' ' )) as word from note) w   
group by word 
order by count desc 
limit 5
;
```

Result:

```
the 20583
of  10388
     9479
and  7611
in   5226
```

9479 is the number of lines. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Please, Tell me more specifically.

Comment: :-))) I just figured out your output. Are you trying to exclude the "word" that occurs 9479 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the split function to -

```
split(word,'\\s+')
```

(instead of a single space, a serious a white characters `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`)

Comment: Thanks for your kindness! But when I tried to run it the way you told me, it still remains. The value has been reduced to 7296 from 9479. If you have any other ideas, can you let me know?

Comment: It's probably NULL. Add `where word is not null` to the query

Comment: I did it the way you told me. I applied the first method(add`hex(word)`), The rest of the results showed a hex value, but the problematic part did not show a hex value. (e.g. `the  20583  746865` `   7298   `) 
At the second method, I used the delimiter in this form(`split(word, '^a-ZA-Z0-9')`). The result was `     7030    / OF PAINTING  33  4F... / ... `. 
Did I do something wrong in the second method?

Comment: I just executed the `where` clause, and the result is the same. It still remains.

Comment: 1st method - empty string? `where word <> ''` 2nd method `'[^a-ZA-Z0-9]'`

Comment: OH! It works!!! The problem is 'empty string'!!! :) Thanks to you, I finally solved the problem. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: In the second method, if I use the [] symbol in a sentence, I get an error

Comment: `split(word,'[^a-ZA-Z0-9]')`